K8s pod cannot reach other pods via a clusterIp service
I have a small home Kuberenetes cluster running on 2 Ubuntu nodes.
In this cluster I am running a few small home applications and for monitoring purposes I've decided to install a Grafana agent on the cluster.
The install was successfull however I've noticed the kube-state-metrics are not being collected and after checking I found that the agent pod cannot communicate with the kube-state-metrics pod via it's clusterIp service when the pods reside on the same node.
The curl request does work when i manually use the pod's IP but all services and ingresses i created did not work.
I did check from other pods in the cluster and they get a response from the kube-state-metrics pod through all the methods I tried.
There are no network policies in the cluster and both the agent and the kube-state-metrics pods are on the same host node.
For now i've moved one of the pods manually but I would like to understand the problem.
